# Am I supposed to buy Lion twice?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore

I've formatted my mac, and I've reinstalled Snow Leopard from installation CD. Successively I've accessed to the mac store to download Lion again and install it on top of the fresh Snow Leopard installation, and suprise: the mac store asks me to buy it again.

I'm using the same user profile (Apple ID).

Comment: You can't run the App Store on Leopard, only on Snow Leopard or Lion, so something odd is happening here. Try installing Snow Leopard rather than Leopard.

Comment: @Mike Scott I meant Snow Leopard, sorry!

Comment: OK, in App Store go to the "Purchased" tab. Does it list your purchases? Do they include Lion? Do you have an "Install" button next to Lion.

Comment: @Mike Scott No, No, No. Lion is the only app I've bought, the other ones I downloaded for free (and they are not in list either). The login with the apple id login has been successfult (my credit card was corretly stored. I'm sure I'm logged with my account).

Comment: You should have gotten a receipt for the purchase of Lion from the App Store. I'd take that and your account Id and contact Apple.

Comment: @Ian C. What's the best way to get support ? I would prefer to not have to call them, and I have seen many forums in the supports page.

Comment: http://www.apple.com/ca/support/mac/app-store/ -- that's the link you're taken to when you click 'Support' in the Quick Links box on the main screen in the App Store app.

Comment: http://www.apple.com/support/mac/app-store/

The "ca" stands for Canada, better use your own country.

Comment: @Loic: good catch. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can't delete this question anymore, so I provide the solution: I had 2 different accounts.

The problem is that I've used my email for one account, instead of using my nickname, and this generated the second account. I think they should recognize emails, and warn you, you already have an account with this email, to avoid issues like mine.

Comment: Was Apple support able to merge your accounts? Or close one?

Comment: Patrick, in the future, in case you are in this situation again, DO NOT delete a question because you found the answer. You did the exact correct thing here, in which you answered your own question. Answering your own question is recommended on Stack Exchange as long as you provide sufficient detail, don't simply state "I fixed it" and leave.

Comment: @Ian C., Apple does not merge or remove Apple ID accounts under any circumstances because (as they told me), they simply cannot.

Answer (score 1):

No. If you buy the Lion upgrade, it can be downloaded and installed on all of the macs you own or control (as long as you aren't using it as a business or commercial manner.)

---

(as an aside)
Getting Lion with a new mac isn't the same as buying the upgrade - you aren't supposed to take that download and use it on other macs. (even if you can figure out how - it's more a licensing issue than a technical one)

Comment: I'm sorry, but you are wrong. Apple allows that installation of Lion on any device that has been authorized under that particular Apple ID: http://osxdaily.com/2011/07/21/install-mac-os-x-lion-multiple-macs/ (Note where it says "One of the great unsung features of Lion is the personal use license which allows you to download OS X Lion once and then install it on all of your authorized personal Macs.) And a copy of the personal use licence: http://osxdaily.com/2011/06/07/single-purchase-of-lion-installs-on-all-macs/ Where you can clearly see in the Apple keynote that you are absolutely allowed.

Comment: Please just edit my answer to make it right :-) Do be aware that your Apple ID doesn't get authorized if you buy a new mac that shipped with Lion from the factory. It authorizes the hardware for a download - not the Apple ID for an upgrade. And no need to be sorry - I'm wrong all the time and truly appreciate when people point it out so I don't spread wrong information :-)

Comment: I would suggest removing it actually. It has already been solved and was just an issue of signing into the wrong Apple ID. I think it would be best to just delete it under the circumstsances :)